# Adding ManyToManyField in correct order

Tags: python, django, manytomanyfield

I am facing an interesting problem, I don't know whether it is a problem, but it is not giving the expected value that I need. Here is my two models for example.

```
class Name(models.Model):
    """ """
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)


class Dir(models.Model):
    name = models.ForeignKey(Name)
    children = models.ManyToManyField('Dir', null=True, blank=True, related_name="dirs")
```

For example, I added two directories in children 'A', 'B'. Now I want to get back my two children in the same order that I added. But the problem is, it is providing me in below order. 'B', 'A'. How to keep the order exactly same as I added ?

Comment: Since Django has no guarantee's of insertion order preservation when it comes to `m2m` fields you'd have to do a `through` table and define the ordering there.

Comment: Thanks. But how can I use through here as the model and its children have the same name 'Dir' ? I tried but cannot really understand how to make.

Comment: Have you tried this?

    `class DirEntry(models.Model):`

        `parent = models.ForeignKey(Dir)`

        `child = models.ForeignKey(Dir)`

        `order = models.IntegerField()`

But as for me, `ManyToManyField` with `through` has too many limitations - e.g. no `add()`, `create()` methods, and managers will not work (I mean redefined `Dir.objects` with some filter) - better use just intermediate model by foreign keys.

Comment: Thanks HighCat. I have fixed my issue by adding another field 'dir_id'. See my below comments.

Answer (score -1):

You could order directories by relationship identifier:

```
parent = Dir(name='parent')
parent.dirs.add(Dir(name='A'))
parent.dirs.add(Dir(name='B'))
children = Dir.dirs.all().order_by('id') # or '-id' if you need reverse order.
```

Only if you use [through](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#intermediary-manytomany) attribute to define intermediary table.

Comment: The insertion id sometimes doesn't give the expected output in my Model structure, but this was nice hints, Thanks. Now I defined my own 'dir_id' field and assign the value in correct order during insert the value. Now I can see the correct output.

Comment: I used a created=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True) on my intermediary model to know the insertion order. Then I can use .order_by('created')